# javascript says that 4 is higher than 16

Tags: javascript, numbers

```
function getNum() {
    num = $('.slicesinput').val();
    num2 = $('.numinput').val();
    if (num === "" || num2 === "") {
        alert('Your inputs may not be empty, else the diagram won\'t work proper...');
    } else {
        if (num > num2) {
            alert('Whoops, ' + num + ' is a higher number than ' + num2 + ', please fix this and try again');
        } else if (num === num2) {
            alert('Woops, ' + num + ' and ' + num2 + ' is the same number...');
        } else {
            progressBarUpdate(num, num2);
        }
    }
}
```

the HTML

```
<p>Number of slices you want</p>
<input name="slices" class="slicesinput" type="text"/>
<p>Out of max slices</p>
<input name="num" class="numinput" type="text"/>
<p>Ex. 3 + 6</p>
<input type="submit" onclick="getNum()"/>
```

When I submit this with ex 4 in the first and 16 in the second it pops up with an alert
"Woops, 4 is a higher number than 16, please fix this and try again", but if i choose 4 and 6 it works fine..? What is the actual problem? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to put your 'num' variables in a Number() function because they might be compared as strings instead of numbers. And you can also change inputs' type to number.

Comment: So... How do you wanna you Number function?

Comment: Try num = Number($('.slicesinput').val());

Comment: Glad to help. Keep it up mate! :)

Answer (score 2):

When you get value of textbox like,

```
num = $('.slicesinput').val();
```

What you're getting is a string value and not a number. So what you're comparing is actually 2 strings and not numbers. You need to parse the String to a Number to make it working

```
num = Number($('.slicesinput').val());
```